# Python Selenium: element is not attached to the page document error acting strangely

Tags: python, selenium

Essentially none of the traditional fixes are working. I have tried implicit and explicit waits, and waiting for the element to be clickable. As you can see below, the stack trace is a standard stale element exception, but the line of code beneath it (what throws the error), should be enough to stop the error I would think? Even stranger, the error does not throw consistently. I would be

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

add_account = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[.='Add another account']" )))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dirty and quick approach : Surround your code in a `try` block and upon encountering a `StaleElementReferenceException` discard the current reference you hold and replace it, possibly by locating the element again once it is attached to the DOM.

```
try:
    add_account = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[.='Add another account']" )))
    add_Account.click()
except StaleElementReferenceException:
    add_account = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[.='Add another account']" )))
    add_account.click()
```

You can enclose the above snippet inside an infinte while loop and have some kind of a flag to break out of it once you are able to click on the element.

Better approach : You can implement the `AbstractEventListener` Class provided by selenium webdriver API to have the `before_find` method wait for the following events to complete:

> 1. `document.readyState` to be equal to `complete`
> 2. `window.jQuery.active` to return `false`
> 3. Wait for angular js to complete its rendering

After implementing the `AbstractEventListener`, wrap your driver object with the implementing class.

`ef_driver = EventFiringWebDriver(driver, EventListener())`

```
class EventListener(AbstractEventListener):
    def before_find(self, by, value, driver):
        wait_for_everything_to_load(driver)

def wait_for_everything_to_load(driver):
"""
Waits for the DOM to load, angular js to complete
"""
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda x:
                                    driver.execute_script("""
    try {
    if (document.readyState !== 'complete') {
        return false; // Page not loaded yet
    }
    if (window.jQuery) {
        if (window.jQuery.active) {
        return false;
        } else if (window.jQuery.ajax && window.jQuery.ajax.active) {
            return false;
        }
    }

        } if (window.angular) {
        if (!window.qa) {
            // Used to track the render cycle finish after loading is complete
            window.qa = {
                doneRendering: false
            };
        }
        // Get the angular injector for this app (change element if necessary)
        var injector = window.angular.element('body').injector();
        // Store providers to use for these checks
        var $rootScope = injector.get('$rootScope');
        var $http = injector.get('$http');
        var $timeout = injector.get('$timeout');
        // Check if digest
        if ($rootScope.$$phase === '$apply' || $rootScope.$$phase === '$digest' || $http.pendingRequests.length !== 0) {
            window.qa.doneRendering = false;
            return false; // Angular digesting or loading data
        }
        if (!window.qa.doneRendering) {
            // Set timeout to mark angular rendering as finished
            $timeout(function () {
                window.qa.doneRendering = true;
            }, 0);
            return false;
    }
    return true;
} catch (ex) {
    return false;
}
        """
                                    )
    )
except:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
while True:
    try:
        add_account = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[.='Add another account']")
        add_account.click()
        break
    except StaleElementReferenceException: 
      print("stale element exception occured")
```